# ADF REST API for Activity Runs not returning data

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rest-api

I'm calling the [Activity Runs Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/rest/api/datafactory/activity-runs/query-by-pipeline-run?tabs=HTTP) from a parent pipeline to capture any errors in a child pipeline.

However, no data, of any kind, is being returned in the `Value` array.

Here are my settings.

[image]

Web activity

[image]

URL

> [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/@{pipeline().globalParameters.SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/@{pipeline().globalParameters.ResourceGrpName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/@{pipeline().DataFactory}/pipelineruns/@{pipeline().RunId}/queryActivityRuns?api-version=2018-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/@%7Bpipeline().globalParameters.SubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/@%7Bpipeline().globalParameters.ResourceGrpName%7D/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/@%7Bpipeline().DataFactory%7D/pipelineruns/@%7Bpipeline().RunId%7D/queryActivityRuns?api-version=2018-06-01)

Body

```
{   "lastUpdatedAfter": "2023-05-23T00:00:00.3345758Z",  
"lastUpdatedBefore": "2023-05-30T00:00:00.3686473Z" }
```

[image]

I've set an activity in the child pipeline to fail.

This is the response - nothing in the `Value` array

```
    {
        "value": [],
        "ADFWebActivityResponseHeaders": {
            "Pragma": "no-cache",
            "x-ms-correlation-request-id": "94cxxxx0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b0842c922b3f",
...
        },
        "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (West Europe)",
        "executionDuration": 0,
        "durationInQueue": {
            "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
        },
        "billingReference": {
            "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
            "billableDuration": [
                {
                    "meterType": "AzureIR",
                    "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                    "unit": "Hours"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I've tried both the parent pipeline runid and the child pipeline runid in the URL and both return an empty `Value` array.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the pipeline whose execution details you want to capture is executed via 'Trigger' mode and not 'Debug' mode. So , you need to publish and trigger the pipeline, capture the pipeline runid and pass the same in the web activity.

Comment: thanks, only a trigger run.  
Our environment is connected to Git and Publish can only be done with a PR merge.
So I can't test this without merging a PR. It is what it is.

Comment: Yes Correct you need to merge it ,.publish and then trigger it

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @AnnuKumari to get activity run details the pipeline should be run with trigger does not debug mode faced same issue but when I triggered it I got an output. Also make sure that is right one and runs exist between the interval specified (UTC).

Also, as you want the activity run details of child pipeline activity. you need to provide its run id as `@{activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineRunId}`

**Sample URL:**

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/@{pipeline().globalParameters.SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/@{pipeline().globalParameters.ResourceGrpName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/@{pipeline().DataFactory}/pipelineruns/@{activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineRunId}/queryActivityRuns?api-version=2018-06-01
```

**My execution:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thanks, only a trigger run.  
Our environment is connected to Git and Publish can only be done with a PR merge.
So I can't test this without merging a PR. It is what it is.