# How to find if a particular notebook in workflow have ran successfully or not in Azure adf?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

There are 9 workflows we have created. each workflow is dependent on previous workflow. 002_ workflow is running by schedule trigger except 002 all are running with event based trigger.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrvfP.png)

Problem statement: problem is there are several notebooks in workflows that are not running daily or maybe they can failed. but campaign_inseason notebbok is critical for me it should run everyday. So can i create another workflow and can i use If activity and in expression i can pass check if this campaign_inseason notebook have ran successfully or not, and if it's True then i will pass wait activity in False case i will pass the campaign_inseason notebook so that it can run.
but problem is how can i  check if this campaign_inseason notebook have ran successfully or not.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbjXg.png)

Answer (score 0):

To get the status of activity inside child pipeline you can use [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/activity-runs/query-by-pipeline-run?tabs=HTTP#code-try-0).

Follow below Process:

- On completion of your **campaign_inseason notebook** activity add web activity to get the status of child pipeline activity with Rest API and configure it like below.

**Sample URL:**

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/@{pipeline().globalParameters.SubscriptionId}/resourceGroups/@{pipeline().globalParameters.ResourceGrpName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/@{pipeline().DataFactory}/pipelineruns/@{activity('Execute Pipeline1').output.pipelineRunId}/queryActivityRuns?api-version=2018-06-01
```

In body pass the last updated before and last updated after parameter with filter of activity name to get status of particular activity.

**Request body:**

```json
{
    "lastUpdatedAfter": "2023-05-25T17:50:00.1653329Z",
    "lastUpdatedBefore": "2023-05-26T17:50:00.1653329Z",
    "filters":[{"operand":"ActivityName","operator":"Equals","values":["Set variable1"]},],
}
```

**My web activity settings**

[image]

**Output of web activity:**

[image]

- After this add If condition activity and check the status from web activity output with expression like below:

```
@if(equals(activity('Web1').output.value.Status,'Succeeded'),true,false)
```

[image]

And place the activities you want accordingly in True and False case.

You can also refer my answer from this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76332324/18043699)